# Relationships between ontology concepts

Tags: ontology

I have a doubt! can an object proprety share domains and ranges? For example,  I have four disjoint classes `A`, `B`, `C`, `D` and an object property 'produces'. Is it possible to state: `produces(A,B)`; `produces(C,D)`. The domains and ranges are different.

or should I have to say:

```
produces1(A,B)
produces2(C,D)
```

Comment: If `A` and `B` are classes, what does `produces(A,B)` mean?

Comment: It means that the concept A is related to concept B with the relationship "produces"  in other words the objectProperty "produces" has as domain the concept "A" and as rang the concept "B". Idem for produces(C,D). Which means (A produces B) and (C produces D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible. Without specified domain or range, the use of an object property does not cause type inferences, and therefore cannot cause inconsistencies.

If you wish to specify domains (equivalently, ranges) and some of the classes you wish to include are disjoint, you want to specify the domain as the **union** of these classes (by default multiple domain assertions are taken as intersection).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but if i use the union of the classes as domain and range of the ObjectProperty which means that the class "A produces B or D" same thing for the class C. 
 what i want to specify is that only A can produces B and only C can produces D (with A, B, C and D disjoint classes)

Comment: That's not how domains and ranges work, they don't express features of the classes but of the property. For class specific assertions of this form, you should use qualified restrictions as superclasses of the class you're describing.

Comment: Thank you for your help.